# iOS - Affect Class Without Reloading View Through ECSlidingViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, ecslidingviewcontroller

I am using ECSlidingViewController, and I have a UIWebView in my class WebViewController. Without reloading the entire view, I'd like to load the URL into the UIWebView when I click on a cell in the MenuViewController.m class.

This is what I have so far:

MenuViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

}

NSString *pdfName = cell.textLabel.text;
WebViewController *webView = [[WebViewController alloc] init];

[webView setWebView:pdfName];

}
```

WebViewController.m

```
@interface WebViewController ()

@end

@implementation WebViewController
@synthesize WebView1;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    self.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7f;
    self.view.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
    self.view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

     if(![self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController isKindOfClass:[MenuViewController class]]) {
    self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Menu"];
}

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];
    CGRect frame = WebView1.frame;

     frame.size.width = 280;       // Your desired width here.
    frame.size.height = 1;        // Set the height to a small one.

    WebView1.frame = frame;

    NSString *fullURL = @"http://www.sluggy.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [WebView1 loadRequest:requestObj];

}

-(void)setWebView:(NSString *)pdfName{

    NSString *homeDir = NSHomeDirectory();
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", homeDir, @"Documents", pdfName];
    NSString *fullURL = @"http://www.google.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

   [WebView1 loadRequest:requestObj];
    [WebView1 reload];
}
```

So I know I'm missing something somewhere. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So, I had to go searching in a roundabout way, and found NSNotificationCenter in relation to updating a label. I will link to the page that describes how to do this, it worked brilliantly:

[Update a label through button from different view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257848/update-a-label-through-button-from-different-view)